# How to select unique records from a 5 column table where the values can be the same but in different orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I used 1 table to do a cross join 4 times giving me 5 columns of data.  I used the same column in all 4 cross joins to get every combination.  The only problem is I get the same data it is in a different order.  I am trying to only get records that are unique.

I can only have one iteration of each set of data, ie 12345 - 12346 - 12347, but not 54321 - 64321 - 74321 or any combo where all the same numbers are combined.  I am stumped.

| Table 1 / column 1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| ... |
| 100 |

```
Select t.col1, t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1, t4.col1
from table1 t 
CROSS JOIN table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table1 t2
CROSS JOIN table1 t3
CROSS JOIN table1 t4
WHERE
    t.col1 != t1.col1 and t.col1 != t2.col1 and t.col1 != t3.col1 and t.col1 != t4.col1 
    and t1.col1 != t2.col1 and t1.col1 != t3.col1 and t1.col1 != t4.col1 
    and t2.col1 != t3.col1 and t2.col1 != t4.col1
    and t3.col1 != t4.col1
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |

Only one of those works, the first one, because all the rest are just combinations of the first. Think of this with the original table having hundreds of rows.

Comment: Seems like you need to `JOIN` where the values are *greater* than the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all `=!` with `<`:

```sql
Select t.col1, t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1, t4.col1
from table1 t 
CROSS JOIN table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table1 t2
CROSS JOIN table1 t3
CROSS JOIN table1 t4
WHERE
    t.col1 < t1.col1 and t.col1 < t2.col1 and t.col1 < t3.col1 and t.col1 < t4.col1 
    and t1.col1 < t2.col1 and t1.col1 < t3.col1 and t1.col1 < t4.col1 
    and t2.col1 < t3.col1 and t2.col1 < t4.col1
    and t3.col1 < t4.col1
```

The problem with `=!` is while you prevent numbers x and y from being the same, you get two joins; one for the case where x < y and one for the case where x > y, leading to unwanted duplicate joins.

Comment: Unbelievable... Thanks for that.  130,680 rows down to 5,445.  and the thing is I knew that but just forgot.  Thanks for your help on this.